# Seeking IMO-level problems about sequences. Eg, showing $a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_n\geq n$ when $a_{k+1}\geq \frac{k a_k}{a_k^2+(k-1)}$ (with conditions)

Tags: sequences-and-series, contest-math

Can you guys recommend a similar problem to me, or modify this one to another question? I'm looking for a problem about sequences.

IMO SHORTLIST 2015 algebra:

> Suppose that a sequence $a_1$, $a_2$, $\ldots$ of positive real numbers satisfies
> $$a_{k+1}\geq \frac{k a_k}{a_k^2+(k-1)}$$ for every positive integer $k$. Prove that
> $$a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_n\geq n$$
> for every $n\geq 2$.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is solved at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G-2lza9SAwI

For more questions, i think you should just google IMO questions.